# No value shown after applying lambda

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a new column with values 1 or 0 based on conditions from multiple columns.

The dataset below is been used.

I tried the following:

`df['passed'] = lambda x: '1' if df[(df['name']=='a') & (df['month'] <8) & (df['score']> 3.5)] else '0'`

```
    'name'  : ['a', 'a', 'a','a',' a','a','a', 's', 's','s','l','a','c','a', 'e','a','g', 'd','c','d','a','f','a','a','a'],
    'month' : [5, 12, 3, 12, 3, 6,7,8,9,10,11,12,4,5,2,6,7,8,3, 4, 7, 6,7,8,8],
    'score' : [2.5, 5, 3.5, 2.5, 5, 3.5,2,3.5,4,2,1.5,1,1.5,4,5.5,2,3,1,2,3.5,4,2,3.5,3,4]})
```

This is the output I get:

```
    name    month   score   passed
0   a   5   2.5 <function <lambda> at 0x1a2050c158>
1   a   12  5.0 <function <lambda> at 0x1a2050c158>
```

Instead of "function lambda, at 0x1a2050c158>" I need a values, either 1 or 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `np.where`

```
df['passed'] = np.where( (df['name']=='a') & (df['month'] <8) & (df['score']> 3.5),1,0)
```

Or

```
df['passed'] = ( (df['name']=='a') & (df['month'] <8) & (df['score']> 3.5)).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df['passed'] = df.apply(lambda row: 1 if (row['name']=='a') and (row.month < 8) and (row.score > 3.5) else 0, axis = 1)
```

Comment: I get 0's in all rows, do you know why is that ?

Comment: @Reda S Because `(df['month'] <8) & (df['score']> 3.5)` is `False` for all rows (at least, all 2 rows from the dataset you showed in the OP).

Comment: I tried it and row has an attribute name, so `row.name` actually takes the index that is why it always gives False, we should replace `row.name` by `row['name']`. The 2 formulas `row.X` and `row['X']` are equivalent (unless X is actually a name attribute of row object as we just shown)

Answer (score 1):

use pandas.Series instead :

```
import pandas as pd
input_dict = {'name'  : ['a', 'a', 'a','a',' a','a','a', 's', 's','s','l','a','c','a', 'e','a','g', 'd','c','d','a','f','a','a','a'],
    'month' : [5, 12, 3, 12, 3, 6,7,8,9,10,11,12,4,5,2,6,7,8,3, 4, 7, 6,7,8,8],
    'score' : [2.5, 5, 3.5, 2.5, 5, 3.5,2,3.5,4,2,1.5,1,1.5,4,5.5,2,3,1,2,3.5,4,2,3.5,3,4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(input_dict)
df['passed'] = pd.Series(['1' if x=='a' and y<8 and z>3.5 else '0' for (x, y, z) in zip(df['name'].values, 
                                                                                          df['month'].values,
                                                                                          df['score'].values)
                           ])
```

Output :

```
name    month   score   passed
0   a   5   2.5 0
1   a   12  5.0 0
2   a   3   3.5 0
3   a   12  2.5 0
4   a   3   5.0 0
5   a   6   3.5 0
6   a   7   2.0 0
7   s   8   3.5 0
8   s   9   4.0 0
9   s   10  2.0 0
10  l   11  1.5 0
11  a   12  1.0 0
12  c   4   1.5 0
13  a   5   4.0 1
14  e   2   5.5 0
15  a   6   2.0 0
16  g   7   3.0 0
17  d   8   1.0 0
18  c   3   2.0 0
19  d   4   3.5 0
20  a   7   4.0 1
21  f   6   2.0 0
22  a   7   3.5 0
23  a   8   3.0 0
24  a   8   4.0 0
```